# KendoUI Window Issue if more than one Window pop is there

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

H,I am using the KendoUI window and I am getting an issue as i have to open 3 Pop up window that contains divs as a Content in it but of different heights.if I select first one say of height 100px and close it and open the second window of height say 200px,it remains at 100px and hence hiding the content of the second popup window and  when i resize the window and close it and when again open it,it remains at the previous dimension that i had resized it.
Why this is happening,not getting any clue on this.Please help me.

```
if (AccountType == "Bank") {
            //alert("Return View For Bank")

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "Popup_Account_Update",
                data: {AccountID:AccountID},
                success: function (response) {

                    $('#Update_Window').empty();
                    $('#Update_Window').html(response);

                    $popup = $("#Update_Window");
                    var wnd = $popup.kendoWindow({
                        //content: Main.rootUrl("Home/Customer/" + customer.attributes[1].value),
                        actions: ["Close"],
                        modal: true,
                        //title: customer.attributes[2].value,
                        visible: false,
                        width: '500px',
                        height: '200px',
                        scrollable: false,
                        //deactivate: function () { wnd.destroy(); }
                    }).data('kendoWindow').center();
                    wnd.open();
                    var tmp = $("#Update_Window").data("kendoWindow");
                    tmp.title("Bank Account Edit");

                }
            });
        }
if (AccountType == "Cash") {
            //alert("Return View For Bank")

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "Popup_Account_Update",
                data: { AccountID: AccountID },
                success: function (response) {

                    $('#Update_Window').empty();
                    $('#Update_Window').html(response);

                    $popup = $("#Update_Window");
                    var wnd1 = $popup.kendoWindow({
                        //content: Main.rootUrl("Home/Customer/" + customer.attributes[1].value),
                        actions: ["Close"],
                        modal: true,
                        //title: customer.attributes[2].value,
                        visible: false,
                        width: '500px',
                        height: '360px',
                        scrollable: false,
                        //deactivate: function () { wnd1.destroy(); }
                    }).data('kendoWindow').center().open();
                    //wnd1.open();
                    var tmp = $("#Update_Window").data("kendoWindow");
                    tmp.title("Cash Account Edit");

                }
            });
        }
<div id="Update_Window" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said: you `close` it, you did not destroy. Closing a `window` means hiding it but it is still there with the same content and attributes.

You should not use `$('#Update_Window').empty();` since this releases the DOM but not the Kendo Window so it will cause a memory leak. Instead of that, use: [`destroy`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/window#methods-destroy).

```
$('#Update_Window').data("kendoWindow").destroy();
```

Anyway, my recommendation is not creating and destroying windows since this has some impact in performance, you should try to reuse it.

Comment: yes..but if we use more than one window of diffrent content height then how to handle it?

Comment: In my case i have to open 3 Pop up window that contains divs as a Content in it but of different height.if I select first one say of height 100px and close it and open the second window of height say 200px,it remains at 100px and hence hiding the content of the second popup window

Comment: No I have to display both the Window as It have different forms in it and I have to Update the Value of the Forms.

Comment: If you might have to display both windows then create two windows and display them with the right size and you can programmatically resize them using `wnd.wrapper.css({ width: 100, height: 300 });`

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/AUN9X/. I create 3 windows. The first restores the width and height when reopened, the second only the height and the third only the width.

Comment: Solved as here I was doing the Action on Same div so kept 3 divs now with different dimensions...Thanks alot..OnaBai